# Needing to slide by 7 slides on Prev-Next

Tags: owl-carousel

I am creating a custom calendar slider using Owl Carousel. It will show 7 days a a time (so 7 slides are active). When I click on the pagination dots, the slides move by 7 slides. However, when using custom Prev-Next buttons, it only moves one slide at a time.

My custom buttons are calling the following:

```
$('.calNextButton').click(function() {
   $('.owl-carousel').trigger('next.owl.carousel');
});

$('.calPrevButton').click(function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
});
```

Is there a way to customize these functions to move by a specific number of slides, instead of just one at a time?

I am using Owl Carousel v2.2.1. I am attaching a screen shot of my calendar slider for your reference.
[Screen Capture of Calendar Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnKjr.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use slideBy option

```
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        slideBy: 7,
    });
```

For more information
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html